# Why my message is not being displayed (in print) when my condition is either True or False?

Tags: python, printing

I have been testing a number of little programs and I have a question regarding one piece of the code that I wrote. Here is the Python code:

```
import turtle
import random

t=turtle.Turtle()
count = 0

for i in range(3):
    a=random.randint(20,30)
    t.circle(a)
    b=int(input("Guess the radius of the circle(range:20-30) "))
    print(b)
    if b==a:
        print("Correct")
        count=count+1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
if i==3:
    t.write("your score is", count)
```

The thing is that when I have condition: `if b==a:`, the program should print `"Correct"` on the console or if condition is False, I should have `"incorrect"` printed on the console. However, it is not printed and I don't get any message on console though I have it in print() in both cases- if condition becomes true or false. Could anyone explain, please, why the message is not displayed. The circle is being drawn and everything else is good, but I am confused with this printing part.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. That is, I see the input prompt and the `Correct/incorrect` text on the terminal. (Along with the circles on a separate graphics window). Also the `t.write(...` line is never executed since `i==3` is never `True`. `i` is only ever 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: That i can be missed that is not about loop counter, I don't have correct/incorrect text printed either and that is my issue. Do you have it on your compiler printed?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the last line:

```
t.write("your score is: ", count)
```

Comment: Which error is in that line?

Comment: There is no error except for this comma, yeah, but I mean the conditional part where it doesn't print "correct" or "incorrect" based on the value it takes randomly and the user gives. So, it's not about t.write() command, it is about conditional part. When I run it it gives the circles that are being drawn, but it doesn't print the message

Comment: There is no problem with the conditions. The correct/incorrect text is printed.

Answer (score 0):

It does print .
And there is a syntax error here:

```
    t.write("your score is" count)
```

You can write is as:

```
    t.write(f"your score is {count}")
```

Comment: Yeah, that is about t.write() command from turtle but I mean print() functions in conditional part: